# How to replace <Esc> with Ctrl-c completely?

Tags: neovim, escape

- NVIM v0.9.1
- Windows10

I usually prefer `<C-c>` rather than `<Esc>` or `<C-[>` which made me think that I want to replace `<Esc>` with `<C-c>` perfectly for almost all situations(command, terminal, insert, change-character).

---

The naive idea was

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<C-c>', '<Esc>', { noremap = true, silent = true })

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('c', '<C-c>', '<Esc>', { noremap = true, silent = true })

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('t', '<C-c>', '<Esc>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

But the problem is that `<C-c>` doesn't behave as expected.

For examples

- When I use change-character mode by hitting `r` and try to leave from the mode with `<C-c>`, it replaces the character with `^C` instead of leaving.
- When I try to leave command mode with `<C-c>`, it exits the mode with the execution of the command (When I use `<Esc>` instead, it will just exit from command mode)

---

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the first problem (`r` mode) for which I believe there are no solution (like for the `<C-v>` mode by the way).

Comment: Probably an XY problem. The core problem is that ESC is too hard to reach. Depending on your hardware and/or OS, you can map your caps lock to different hold and tab actions. For me capslock, when pressed alone, sends ESC, while when pressed together with a letter sends that letter with CTRL (broad speaking, I have much more edge cases depending on the OS I'm on, but you get the idea). I think this is the much smarter way, because sometimes both ESC and C-c are used differently. I.e. on Telescope C-c cancels while ESC leaves insert mode.

Comment: Actually I found replacing capslock with esc much easier! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not add the mapping and it solves the second problem (the command mode).

For the replace mode (`r`) I believe there are no way to go around it.

The same for literal insert mode (`<C-v>`).

Comment: Note that C-c differs from escape when using, eg, `5iX`.